# moving backward causes error: "“Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated…”

Tags: javascript, ajax

I move back and forth between two link and changing the content using ajax.
The problem is when I tried to move backward all the way to index.php

here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="bk/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <a href="admin.html">Admin</a>
        <a href="content.html">Get Content</a>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('body').find('a').off('click').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));

        callPage($(this).attr('href'));
    });

    function callPage(ref) {
        $.get(
            ref,
            function(data) {
                $('#content').html(data);
            },
            'text'
        );
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
        callPage(location.pathname.split('/').pop());
    });
});
</script>
```

the content of admin.html and content.html are Admin and Hello World, respectively wrapped with h1 tag. Whenever I press the back button and reached the index, I always encounter this error:

[Error message in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1AiW.png)

and in the browser:
[view in browser after reaching the index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUQJ1.png)

It was supposedly not like that. Any suggestion what might be the reasons for that?

Comment: I doubt you will get many answers unless you add some code to your question. See this guide for help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I modify the question entirely. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get back to index.html, it is probably trying to load a copy of itself into div#content. This would probably cause lots of unexpected results: It's going to be loading a second copy of your jquery library and all sorts of other weird things.

A more reliable practice would be to put your "virtual" path after a hash tag, like this: `http://test.com/index.html#/admin.html`. That way reload/refresh events would also work. Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <a href="#/admin.html">Admin</a>
        <a href="#/content.html">Get Content</a>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <script>
        $(function() {

            function callPage(ref) {
                if(ref!=='') {
                    $.get(
                        ref,
                        function(data) {
                            $('#content').html(data);
                        },
                        'text'
                    );
                 } else $('#content').html('');
            }

            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

            var fnHashchange = function() {
                 var path = location.hash.replace(/^#/,'');
                callPage(path);
            }
            $(window).on('hashchange', fnHashchange);
            fnHashchange();
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, as an aside, it's not really a good practice to put the script tag outside of the html tag. Most browsers will parse it, but I don't believe it's legal html.